# AdMob interstitial size is very big for my Android phone

Tags: android, admob

My AdMob interstitial ads are showing with very big dimensions. Can someone help me resolve this problem?

I use the virtual device (emulator) of Android Studio and also my own Android phone. It is not working on both.

Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to post the code that you have written already. Also, make sure to take a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Comment: I added the code before but it told me "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details"

Comment: Hi LAD, thanks for your reply, unfortunately, the link that you share is about banner not interstitial AdMob :)